# Why is my SQL code on phpMyAdmin only showing 30 rows of data when my database clearly has more?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Having a bit of an issue where my SQL code is only throwing back 30 rows of data when there is clearly more, any ideas?
Code attached!
Thanks
Tom :)

```
SELECT wrap.name, wrap_date.start_date, wrap_date.end_date
FROM wrap
INNER JOIN wrap_date ON wrap.id = wrap_date.id
```

Comment: There are two tables, and your JOIN filters out the ones that don't have a matching id in both.

Comment: Not looking at it right now, but isn't there a dropdown menu in phpmyadmin that limits the number of results per page?

Comment: @joshstrike yes, and it defaults to 30.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether phpMyAdmin adds a `LIMIT` statement on your query? If not, can you please post more details about the number of tuples on the `wrap` and `wrap_date` tables.

Answer (score 0):

'INNER JOIN' might filters out some rows. Try the following and see if you get more than 30 rows:

```
SELECT wrap.name, wrap_date.start_date, wrap_date.end_date
FROM wrap
LEFT JOIN wrap_date ON wrap.id = wrap_date.id
```

--or

```
SELECT wrap.name, wrap_date.start_date, wrap_date.end_date
FROM wrap
RIGHT JOIN wrap_date ON wrap.id = wrap_date.id
```